# term query returns 0 results elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a following document:

```
        {
            "_index": "testrest",
            "_type": "testrest",
            "_id": "sadfasdfw1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {,
                "s_item_name": "Create",
                "request_id": "35",
                "Result": "Match",
            }
        },
```

I am trying to get records with `term` value `Match` in `Result` field and `request_id` of `35`.

Here's my query:

```
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "must": [ 
        { "term":  { "Result": "Match" }}
      ],
      "filter": {
        "term": {
            "request_id": "35"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I am getting `0` results.

Replacing `term` with `match` gives me results though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `Result` is a `text` field, and thus, it is analyzed and the value is indexed as `match` instead of `Match`.

In general, you should [not use a `term` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html#avoid-term-query-text-fields), but prefer a `match` query instead. In your case, that would solve the issue.

If you absolutely want to use a `term` query and have a field called `Result.keyword`, then you can also do that.

So to recap:

```
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "must": [ 
        { "match":  { "Result": "Match" }}         <-- use match query
      ],
      "filter": {
        "term": {
            "request_id": "35"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "must": [ 
        { "term":  { "Result.keyword": "Match" }}  <-- use term query on keyword field
      ],
      "filter": {
        "term": {
            "request_id": "35"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```